# C++: Inheritance, assigning

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm learning C++, currently I'm at inheritance of classes and dynamic memory allocation for objects. I'm doing some exercises, and right now I'm stuck on some strange crash of my application.

The problem lies in assigning derived class to new object. Everything looks fine, until destructors are starting to work, I analyzed everything and I cannot find mistake. Code should be pretty simple, class cd stores simple data and "classic" is adding one field.

(The main problem is that app is crashing at the end)

This is source code I hope someone will be able to help me

```
#ifndef CLASSIC_H_
#define CLASSIC_H_

class Cd
{
private:
    char* performers;
    char* label;
    int selection;
    double playtime;
public:
    Cd(char* s1, char* s2, int n, double x);
    Cd(const Cd& d);
    Cd();
    virtual ~Cd();
    virtual void Report() const;
    Cd& operator=(const Cd& d);
};

class Classic : public Cd
{
private:
    char* maintrack;
public:
    Classic(char* mt, char* s1, char* s2, int n, double x);
    Classic();
    Classic(const Classic& c);
    Classic(char* mt, const Cd& d);
    virtual void Report() const;
    virtual ~Classic();
    Classic& operator=(const Classic& c);
};

#endif



using std::strcpy;
Cd::Cd(char* s1, char* s2, int n, double x)
{

    performers = new char[strlen(s1) + 1];
    strcpy(performers, s1);

    label = new char[strlen(s2) + 1];
    strcpy(label, s2);

    selection = n;
    playtime = x;
}

Cd::Cd(const Cd& d)
{
    performers = new char[strlen(d.performers) + 1];
    strcpy(performers, d.performers);

    label = new char[strlen(d.label) + 1];
    strcpy(label, d.label);

    selection = d.selection;
    playtime = d.playtime;
}    

Cd::~Cd()
{

    delete [] performers;
    delete [] label;
}

Cd::Cd()
{
    performers = new char[1];
    performers[0] = '\0';

    label = new char[1];
    label[0] = '\0';

    selection = 0;
    playtime = 0;
}


Cd& Cd::operator=(const Cd& d)
{
    if (this == &d)
        return *this;

    delete [] performers;
    delete [] label;

    performers = new char[strlen(d.performers) + 1];
    strcpy(performers, d.performers);

    label = new char[strlen(d.label) + 1];
    strcpy(label, d.label);

    selection = d.selection;
    playtime = d.playtime;
    return *this;
}


void Cd::Report() const
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << performers << endl;
    cout << label << endl;
    cout << selection << endl;
    cout << playtime << endl;
}


Classic::Classic(char* mt, char* s1, char* s2, int n, double x)
    : Cd(s1, s2, n, x)
{
    maintrack = new char[strlen(mt) + 1];
    strcpy(maintrack, mt);
}

Classic::Classic() : Cd()
{
    maintrack = new char[1];
    maintrack[0] = '\0';
}

Classic::Classic(const Classic& c) : Cd(c)
{
    maintrack = new char[strlen(c.maintrack) + 1];
    strcpy(maintrack, c.maintrack);
}

Classic::Classic(char* mt, const Cd& d) : Cd(d)
{
    maintrack = new char[strlen(mt) + 1];
    strcpy(maintrack, mt);
}

void Classic::Report() const
{
    Cd::Report();
    std::cout << maintrack << std::endl;
}

Classic::~Classic()
{
    delete [] maintrack;
}

Classic& Classic::operator=(const Classic& c)
{
    if (this == &c)
        return *this;

    Cd::operator=(c);
    delete [] maintrack;

    maintrack = new char[strlen(c.maintrack)];
    strcpy(maintrack, c.maintrack);

    return *this;
}







#include <iostream>
#include "classic.h"
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void Bravo(const Cd& disk);

int main()
{
    Cd c1("Beatles", "Capitol", 14, 35.5);
    Classic c2 = Classic("Sonata fortepianowa B-dur, Fantazja C-moll",
                         "Alfred Brendel", "Philips", 2, 57.17);


    Classic copy;
    copy = c2;

    copy.Report();


    system("pause");


    return 0;
}

void Bravo(const Cd& disk)
{
    disk.Report();
}
```

Comment: Is the application giving an error message when it crashes? If so you should post that as well.

Comment: Run your program in a debugger and you'll see where the crash is.

Comment: @Chris the .cpp code is there under "#endif."

Comment: I suspect if you use `std::string` instead of C-style `char*` strings, your problem will just go away.

Comment: And yes, following up on what @interjay said, do a backtrace while debugging.  Backtrace is a miracle worker.

Comment: Since you are learning C++, you  might consider using `std::string` instead of `char*` everywhere.

Comment: The error message that I receive: "Windows has triggered a breakpoint in DrugiProjekt.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in DrugiProjekt.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while DrugiProjekt.exe has focus.

The output window may have more diagnostic information." But it's not helpfull. I'm working curently in Visual Studio 2010 and I'm not familiar with debugger in this environment.

Comment: `maintrack = new char[strlen(c.maintrack)];` shouldn't that be `maintrack = new char[strlen(c.maintrack) + 1];`?

Comment: Yes I can use std::string, but I want to allocate memory to char* and use new. That's my exercise and  I want to finish it.

Comment: Yes!!!! Thank you Matthew, the lack of + 1 was a problem

Comment: @JackRadcliffe: backtracing: solving every problem from program crashes to getting ips to making coffee to decrypting blogs.

Comment: If you insist on using `char *` directly instead of using `std::string`, at least have the decency to use it to create your own string class, then use the string class in the rest of the code. Spreading C-style string manipulation throughout your code is *begging* for trouble!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your copy constructor for `Classic`.  However, this just highlights the perils of doing your own string manipulation.  I'd suggest rewriting this entire exercise with no `char*` and using `std::string` instead.

```
Classic& Classic::operator=(const Classic& c)
{
    if (this == &c)
        return *this;

    Cd::operator=(c);
    delete [] maintrack;

        // you need strlen(c.maintrack) + 1
    maintrack = new char[strlen(c.maintrack)];
    strcpy(maintrack, c.maintrack);

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Are you a faster version of me

Comment: Yes, I've just realized this. Sure using std::string would be simple but It's for training so this is on char* and 'new'. Anyway Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Possible memory corruption in Classic& Classic::operator=(const Classic& c) :

```
maintrack = new char[strlen(c.maintrack)];
strcpy(maintrack, c.maintrack);
```

replace with:

```
maintrack = new char[strlen(c.maintrack) + 1];
strcpy(maintrack, c.maintrack);
```

That said, why exactly aren't you just using the string class that's part of the standard library?  It would save you this and many other headaches.  It does all of the memory management, null termination, etc. all automatically.

```
string maintrack;
char * derp = "derp";
maintrack = derp; // valid
maintrack = "derp"; // valid
maintrack = another_string; // valid
```